# Why does chrome style inspector show style from .scss?

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools

When I use the 'styles' tab of the Google Chrome developer tools, it reports one of my styles as coming from the .scss file. How is this possible - I thought all .scss had to be flattened and read from a .css file:

[image]

Comment: Chrome supports [source maps](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When you compile your sass into css, you have an option to generate a source map file. At the end of the css file you will find a reference to a map file which will be located in the same folder location as your css, with a .map extension.

This is used by chrome inspector to help development. You can turn it off in chrome inspector or just remove the reference to the source map from the css or remove the option to generate the source map in the first place.

If you just want chrome to show the css and are happy to keep the source map file you can just turn off the option. To turn off the option in Chrome Developer Tools, open up inspector and go to Settings. Look in the Sources category within the Preferences section, and untick "Enable css source maps"

Comment: A few years late to this party but great response!

Comment: Excelling answer; nothing more needs to be said.